# Is there a name for dot-separated case?

Tags: naming-conventions

We have `camelCase`, `PascalCase`, `snake_case`, and `kebab-case`. Is there a name for `dot.separated.case`?

Maybe there isn't a name for it, maybe I can't properly word my question for Google, but I can't find anything for it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether dot-separation could ever be considered _any case_, given the semantics related to property / namespace access that it usually carries, even when used in strings.

Comment: I usually see it described as **period.separated** in R. It's the only language that I know of where it's truly just a naming convention and doesn't have the same syntactic meaning as in other languages.

Comment: Dots usually separate distinct units.

Comment: I disagree with comments saying this is not a thing: although similar notation is indeed used for hierarchic access, this is not the only usage. And with web APIs, query parameters, interpretation may or may not slice values into paths. For properties files, for example, one typically uses names exactly as-is, without added semantics. So I think it is good to ask for a name to use for this convention which exists in the wild.

Answer (score 8):

The "dot case format" or "dot notation" is the common denotation here. The format often used in property files, resource-bundles or yaml-files.

It's basically a convention that makes it easier to see what properties are related.

For example:

```
person.title="Title" 
person.surname="Surname" 
person.job.description="Some description"
```

You can easily collect similar properties by filtering the prefix like 'person.' to only see the properties defined for a person.

The dot.case format is also used in maven to name properties. E.g:

```
${project.build.directory}
```

See also [the maven pom properties](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties)

Comment: OK, I don't disagree with anything you wrote here, but the main question is whether there is a name for such a thing. You spend the entire answer explaining the formatting, but only the first sentence actually mentions what the name is, answering the question but providing no references. Can you provide a reference of who other than you calls it "dot case format" for example? Again I'm not disputing you, but part of supplying information on Stack Overflow, if it's not something like a programming algorithm you can test, is providing references. Can you share where you got that info? Thanks.